# Software Update stuck in the middle. 13.04

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

So I finally installed Ubuntu 13.04. Everthing was fine, until I tried to update software. I just got this:

[image: Screenshot]

It just stays that all night long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kill it / Force restart the system. Then, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I only had to make: "sudo dpkg --configure -a" first. 

I'm wondering, why I got this issue? What makes it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think that there was a package which wasn't configured correctly on install (and therefore incomplete), which dpkg wanted to have fixed before allowing anything new.